# $\exp(a_0 + a_1 \sin(x) + a_2 \sin(2x) + ...) = b_0 + b_1 \sin(x) + b_2 \sin(2x) + b_3 \sin(3x) + c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \cos(2x) + ...$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, fourier-series, closed-form

I was thinking about fourier series.
Alot is known about it.

But I wonder

$$\exp(a_0 + a_1 \sin(x) + a_2 \sin(2x) + a_3 \sin(3x) + ...) = b_0 + b_1 \sin(x) + b_2 \sin(2x)+ ... + c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \cos(2x) + ...$$

Is it possible to "simply" express $a_i$ in terms of $b_i,c_i$ or vice versa ?

I use "simply" because ofcourse we can use the fourier series coefficients formula for the LHS and set then equal to the coefficients formula of the RHS. That would give a system of equations such as $\int f(x) \sin(nx) dx = \int \exp(f(y)) \sin(ny) dy $.
OR we could in the analytic case take the taylor series on both sides and equate them.
OR ( also in the analytic case) we could use carleman matrices for function composition.
But I mean something " simple " like a system of lineair equations or polynomial relationships.

Comment: Note that the even part of the right hand side is a constant. The even part of the left hand side is $2e^{a_0}$ times the $\cosh$ of an odd function, which is most likely not a constant.

Comment: Im considering the fact that $sin(-x) = - sin(x)$ and how this influences the equations.
Maybe we need some sums of cosines too. 
@robjohn I did not completely understand what you said but Im guessing its basicly the same thing ?

Comment: This is why context is important. Without more context, all one sees is what is written and as written, the equations need $a_k=b_k=0$ for $k\ge1$.

Comment: @robjohn yes you are right. Im sorry. I will edit.